# Does math exist to find an equation for this?

Tags: calculus

I found a puzzle for myself. I have had only a year of calculus. I am just wondering if it is solvable and what type of math is needed to do so.

My puzzle is this following image that I generated
[image]
Domain (X: (0, 1), Y:(0,1))

I am a programmer, so drawing this equation was easy for me. Unfortunately right now I cant figure out the formula for it so I am doing a very expensive iterative formula for it. You can see the code [here](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/XlcXD8) if you want.

What this graph is showing is a graph of sin(x) based on the normals and location of a bigger sin(x) graph.

There are essentially two functions involved.

```
f(x) = sin(x * 4 * π) * 0.4 + 0.5
```

and

```
g(x) = sin(x * 100) * 0.1
```

f(x) describes the main shape, g(x) describes a displacement from f(x). Basically I take the normal of f(x) and place a dot g(x) units along it.

I suppose you could consider it like I am graphing g(x) on f(x)'s warped axis.

Is there any math that can describe this relation?

If you wanted to simplify the problem you could just make f(x) = x. The resulting image would look like this:
[image]
If you unwarped that image (since it is stretched to a rectangle) and rotated it 45 degrees you would simply have a graph of g(x).

Comment: You have the equation of the curve (which is what you coded) and I see no "very expensive iterative formula". So what ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine you have a curve described by the parametric expression

$$
x(t) = t \quad\mbox{and}\quad y(t)= f(t)
$$

It is possible to calculate a tangential vector at each point along the curve as

$$
\mathbf{v} = \left(\frac{dx}{dt},\frac{dy}{dt} \right) = \left(1,\frac{df(t)}{dt}\right)
$$

A perpendicular vector to $\mathbf{v}$ is

$$
\mathbf{u} = \left(\frac{df(t)}{dt},-1\right)
$$

as can be seen from the fact that $\langle \mathbf{u}|\mathbf{v}\rangle = 0$. You could divide it by its norm so that $\langle \mathbf{u}|\mathbf{u}\rangle = 1$

$$
\mathbf{u}' = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + (df(t)/dt)^2}}\left(\frac{df(t)}{dt},-1\right)
$$

Now that you have the normal vector, you just need to move along it by a certain number, given by your function $g$, the resulting curve is then parametrized by

$$
(x',y') = (t, f(t)) + \mathbf{u}'g(t) = \left(t, f(t) \right) + \frac{g(t)}{\sqrt{1 + (df/dt)^2}}\left(\frac{df(t)}{dt},-1\right)
$$

Comment: This is the correct solution for what OP *says* he wants to do. If I'm correctly reading the cited program, however, OP should note that the program's output does not quite match. (I'm not talking about the `tx1` and `iGlobalTime` adjustments.) As the non-displaced plot points are `(x, by)`, differentiation should be done with respect to `x`; the formula `d = cos(dom) * 0.4` (ostensibly the derivative of `by = sin(dom) * 0.4 + 0.5`) fails to apply the Chain Rule to accommodate the fact that `dom = x * 4.0 * 3.141592 + tx1`. The proper formula there is `d = cos(dom) * 0.4 * 4.0 * 3.141592`.